# How can you set the browser homepage using the extension manifest?

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm making an extension which replaces the users new tab page, and i would also like it to replace the users start up homepage. Right now in my manifest I'm using:

```
"chrome_settings_overrides" : {
"homepage": "givr/index.html"
},
```

But when i try to install the extension I get the error stating it's not a valid value: 
"ErrorInvalid value for overriding homepage url: '[givr/index.html]'."

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/1125128.

Comment: I could work around this if there was a way to set the new tab page as the startup page. If I could put in an 'http/https' link to 'chrome://newtab'.   Does anyone know if there's a way to open a new tab via a regular url?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this, it worked for me:

```
"chrome_settings_overrides" : {
    "homepage": "https://own.intra.site/index.html"
 }
```